# GUI Video transcoder with VA-API (Handbrake alternative)

Tags: ffmpeg, amd, vaapi, handbrake

I'm looking for an alternative to Handbrake. Sadly, it doesn't support VA-API, so you have to install separate support for QSV/VCN/NVENC. While I don't know how bad the situation with
Intel and NVIDIA is, the situation for AMD is abysmal. To get hardware encoding for Handbrake, you need to install the AMDGPU-Pro Stack and the separate AMF module. AMDGPU support for various Linux distributions is slim at best, so that's basically no option for many. On the other hand, it's a really great toolbox. Sure, you can simply use FFMPEG, but that's not really a practical option as you have to do too much googling to find anything.

Does anybody know any alternative, like Handbrake with added VA-API support, or a similarly good GUI for FFMPEG?

Comment: Perhaps time for someone or some group to start an open source project to front FFMPEG and compete with Handbrake.  There's no love for VAAPI at handbrake with the current curators of the project unfortunately.

Alternatively a fork of Handbrake and someone adds VAAPI?

Comment: For all I know, there is on some capacity, but it's only available in the AUR. So someone bringing it to other distros would be nice